# Show number of months between two dates

Tags: php, date, symfony4

I'd like to get number of months between two date but I get this error:

> DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

This is the function:

```
function getMonthDiff()
{
    $currentDateTime = new \DateTime;
    $dateTimeInTheFuture = new \DateTime($this->getSalarie()->getDateEmbauche());
    $dateInterval = $dateTimeInTheFuture->diff($currentDateTime);
    $totalMonths = 12 * $dateInterval->y + $dateInterval->m;

    return $totalMonths;

}
```

This is how I show it in twig:

```
{{ entity.monthDiff }}
```

This is the getDateEmbauche function

```
public function getDateEmbauche(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->dateEmbauche;
}
```

Comment: Run `var_dump($this->getSalarie()->getDateEmbauche());`  to see what that value is. Perhaps already an instance of a DateTime object.

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/php-exercises/php-date-exercise-4.php

Comment: Please edit your question and add your getDateEmbauche() function body

Comment: @AlexHowansky var_dump($this->getSalarie()->getDateEmbauche());

`object(DateTime)#7594 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2011-01-14 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" `

Comment: @M4HdYaR , I have edited my quetsion

Comment: @hous `getDateEmbauche()` returns a [`DateTimeInterface`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php) (or `null`). You can assign it directly to a `DateTime` object.

Comment: @msg , oh yes that's it. thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) :

> DateTime::__construct Returns new **DateTime** object

And

> public DateTime::__construct ([ string $time = "now" [, DateTimeZone
>   $timezone = NULL ]] )

So DateTime needs **String** Parameter but you are giving it a **DateTime Object**.

Change it like this :

```
function getMonthDiff()
{
    $currentDateTime = new \DateTime;
    $dateTimeInTheFuture = $this->getSalarie()->getDateEmbauche();
    $dateInterval = $dateTimeInTheFuture->diff($currentDateTime);
    $totalMonths = 12 * $dateInterval->y + $dateInterval->m;

    return $totalMonths;

}
```